# How to make Windows notification display application title instead of EXE filename?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm using the code below to send Windows notifications. It's working, but the notification window's title is showing the exe filename instead of the name of my application as defined in `Application.Title`.

I want the notification to display 'My application' on the title, but instead, it's displaying 'notif', as displayed on the image below :

[image]

What am I missing?

Project source :

```
program notif;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  unit1 in '..\unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.Title := 'My application';
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Unit source :

```
unit unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Notification;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    NotificationCenter1: TNotificationCenter;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyNotification: TNotification; //Defines a TNotification variable
  begin
  MyNotification := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification; //Creates the notification
  try
    MyNotification.Name := 'My application name'; //Defines the name of the notification.
    MyNotification.Title := 'Title'; //Defines the name that appears when the notification is presented.
    MyNotification.AlertBody := 'Hello, im here'; //Defines the body of the notification that appears below the title.

    NotificationCenter1.PresentNotification(MyNotification); //Presents the notification on the screen.
  finally
    MyNotification.Free; //Frees the variable
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Please post code you're actually using - the one you posted won't compile (as seen by the syntax highlighting). [Which platform are you targeting?](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Notification.TNotification.Title)

Comment: Try setting the application name in your assembly manifest. `<assemblyIdentity name="Delphi Rules" version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" type="win32"/>`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I updated the question with full code and notification image.

Comment: @IanBoyd I do this on the version info resource, but the notification is not getting there

Comment: @AmigoJack Edited the question with full compilable code

Comment: @delphirules The version information resource is different from the **Assembly Manifest** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/assembly-manifests)

Comment: @AmigoJack: Doesn't the *Windows notification* and use of EXE in the title say which platform is being targeted?

Comment: Using `WinRT` and `Winapi.UI.Notifications`, you can make notifications with images, and customize the title, text, image, icon and a lot more. There is a learning curve to It. Try playing around with `TToastNotificationManager` and `TToastNotification`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WinRT for this with the help of `Winapi.UI.Notifications`. I have made a custom class to make this easier.

Still a work in progress, so not everything works as expected, but It should be able to do the basics.

Example:

[image: gif animation of notification]

```
{***********************************************************}
{                Codruts Notification Manager               }
{                                                           }
{                        version 1.0                        }
{                                                           }
{                                                           }
{                                                           }
{                                                           }
{                                                           }
{              Copyright 2023 Codrut Software               }
{***********************************************************}

{$SCOPEDENUMS ON}

unit Cod.NotificationManager;

interface
  uses
  // System
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Forms,

  // Windows RT (Runtime)
  Winapi.Winrt,
  Winapi.Winrt.Utils,
  Winapi.DataRT,
  Winapi.UI.Notifications,

  // Winapi
  Winapi.CommonTypes,
  Winapi.Foundation;

  type
    // Cardinals
    TSoundEventValue = (
      Default,
      NotificationDefault,
      NotificationIM,
      NotificationMail,
      NotificationReminder,
      NotificationSMS,
      NotificationLoopingAlarm,
      NotificationLoopingAlarm2,
      NotificationLoopingAlarm3,
      NotificationLoopingAlarm4,
      NotificationLoopingAlarm5,
      NotificationLoopingAlarm6,
      NotificationLoopingAlarm7,
      NotificationLoopingAlarm8,
      NotificationLoopingAlarm9,
      NotificationLoopingAlarm10,
      NotificationLoopingCall,
      NotificationLoopingCall2,
      NotificationLoopingCall3,
      NotificationLoopingCall4,
      NotificationLoopingCall5,
      NotificationLoopingCall6,
      NotificationLoopingCall7,
      NotificationLoopingCall8,
      NotificationLoopingCall9,
      NotificationLoopingCall10
    );

    TWinBoolean = (Default, False, True);
    TImagePlacement = (Default, Hero, LogoOverride);
    TImageCrop = (Default, Circle);
    TInputType = (Text, Selection);

    TXMLInterface = Xml_Dom_IXmlDocument;

    // Records
    (* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/tiles/toastschema/element-header *)
    TNotificationHeader = record
      ID: string;
      Title: string;
      Arguments: string;
      ActivationType: string;

      function ToXML: string;
    end;

    (* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=xml *)
    TInputItem = record
      ID: string;
      Content: string;

      function ToXML: string;
    end;

    TNotificationInput = record
      ID: string;
      InputType: TInputType;
      PlaceHolder: string;
      Title: string;

      Selections: TArray<TInputItem>;

      function ToXML: string;
    end;

    (* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/tiles/toastschema/element-image *)
    TNotificationImage = record
      ImageQuery: string;
      Alt: string;
      Source: string; // URL or Local file path
      Placement: TImagePlacement;
      HintCrop: TImageCrop;

      function ToXML: string;
    end;

    (* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/tiles/toastschema/element-audio *)
    TNotificationAudio = record
      Sound: TSoundEventValue;
      Loop: TWinBoolean;
      Silent: TWinBoolean;

      function ToXML: string;
    end;

    (* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/tiles/toastschema/element-progress *)
    TNotificationProgress = record
      Title: string;
      Status: string; // Name, such as "installing" or "downloading"
      Value: single; // 0.0 - 1.0
      ValueOverride: string; // Override percentage text

      function ToXML: string;
    end;

    // Classes
    TNotification = class(TObject)
    private
      FTitle: string;
      FText: string;
      FTextExtra: string;

      FXML: TXMLInterface;

      FToast: IToastNotification;

      function BuildXMLDoc: TXMLInterface;

    public
      // Basic
      property Title: string read FTitle write FTitle;
      property Text: string read FText write FText;
      property TextExtra: string read FTextExtra write FTextExtra;

      // Advanced
      var
      Image: TNotificationImage;
      Audio: TNotificationAudio;
      Progress: TNotificationProgress;
      Input: TNotificationInput;
      Header: TNotificationHeader;

      property Toast: IToastNotification read FToast;

      // Procs
      function ToXML: string;

      procedure UpdateToastInterface;

      // Constructors
      constructor Create;
      destructor Destroy; override;

    end;

    TNotificationManager = class(TObject)
    private
      FNotifier: IToastNotifier;
      FApplicationName: string;

      // Notifier
      procedure RebuildNotifier;

      // Setters
      procedure SetAppName(const Value: string);

    public
      // Notificaitons
      procedure ShowNotification(Notification: TNotification);
      procedure HideNotification(Notification: TNotification);

      // App
      property ApplicationName: string read FApplicationName write SetAppName;

      // Utils
      function CreateNewNotification: TNotification;

      // Constructors
      constructor Create;
      destructor Destroy; override;
    end;

  // Utils
  function AudioTypeToString(AType: TSoundEventValue): string;
  function WinBooleanToString(AType: TWinBoolean): string;
  function StringToRTString(Value: string): HSTRING; // Needs to be freed with WindowsDeleteString

  // XML
  function EncapsulateXML(Name: string; Container: string; Tags: string = ''): string;
  function CreateNewXMLInterface: TXMLInterface;
  function StringToXMLDocument(Str: string): TXMLInterface;
  function XMLDocumentToString(AXML: TXMLInterface): string;
  procedure XMLDocumentEdit(AXML: TXMLInterface; NewContents: string);

implementation

const
  NOTIF_BUILD_ERR = 'Notification toast has not been built. E:UpdateToastInterface';

{ TNotificationAudio }

function AudioTypeToString(AType: TSoundEventValue): string;
begin
  case AType of
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationDefault: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Default';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationIM: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.IM';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationMail: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Mail';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationReminder: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Reminder';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationSMS: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.SMS';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingAlarm: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingAlarm2: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm2';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingAlarm3: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm3';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingAlarm4: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm4';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingAlarm5: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm5';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingAlarm6: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm6';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingAlarm7: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm7';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingAlarm8: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm8';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingAlarm9: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm9';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingAlarm10: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm10';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingCall: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Call';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingCall2: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Call2';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingCall3: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Call3';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingCall4: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Call4';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingCall5: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Call5';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingCall6: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Call6';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingCall7: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Call7';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingCall8: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Call8';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingCall9: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Call9';
    TSoundEventValue.NotificationLoopingCall10: Result := 'ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Call10';

    else Result := '';
  end;
end;

function WinBooleanToString(AType: TWinBoolean): string;
begin
  case AType of
    TWinBoolean.Default: Result := 'default';
    TWinBoolean.False: Result := 'false';
    TWinBoolean.True: Result := 'true';
  end;
end;

function StringToRTString(Value: string): HSTRING;
begin
  if NOT Succeeded(
    WindowsCreateString(PWideChar(Value), Length(Value), Result)
  )
  then raise Exception.CreateFmt('Unable to create HString for %s', [ Value ] );
end;

function EncapsulateXML(Name: string; Container, Tags: string): string;
var
  TagBegin, TagEnd: string;
begin
  if Container <> '' then
    TagEnd := Format('</%S>', [Name])
  else
    TagEnd := '';

  TagBegin := Format('<%S', [Name]);
  if Tags <> '' then
    TagBegin := Format('%S %S', [TagBegin, Tags]);

  if Container <> '' then
    TagBegin := TagBegin + '>'
  else
    TagBegin := TagBegin + '/>';

  Result := TagBegin + Container + TagEnd;
end;

function StringToXMLDocument(Str: string): TXMLInterface;
begin
  Result := CreateNewXMLInterface;
  XMLDocumentEdit(Result, Str);
end;

function CreateNewXMLInterface: TXMLInterface;
var
  Manager: TToastNotificationManager;
begin
  Manager := TToastNotificationManager.Create;
  try
    Result := Manager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
    XMLDocumentEdit(Result, '<xml />');
  finally
    Manager.Free;
  end;
end;

function XMLDocumentToString(AXML: TXMLInterface): string;
  function HStringToString(Src: HSTRING): String;
  var
    c: Cardinal;
  begin
    c := WindowsGetStringLen(Src);
    Result := WindowsGetStringRawBuffer(Src, @c);
  end;

begin
  Result := HStringToString(
    ( AXML.DocumentElement as Xml_Dom_IXmlNodeSerializer ).GetXml
  );
end;

procedure XMLDocumentEdit(AXML: TXMLInterface; NewContents: string);
var
  hXML: HSTRING;
begin
  hXML := StringToRTString( NewContents );
  try
    (AXML as Xml_Dom_IXmlDocumentIO).LoadXml( hXML );
  finally
    WindowsDeleteString( hXML );
  end;
end;

function TNotificationAudio.ToXML: string;
begin
  Result := '';

  if Sound <> TSoundEventValue.Default then
    Result := Result + 'src="' + AudioTypeToString(Sound) + '" ';

  if Loop <> TWinBoolean.Default then
    Result := Result + 'loop="' + WinBooleanToString(Loop) + '" ';

  if Silent <> TWinBoolean.Default then
    Result := Result + 'silent="' + WinBooleanToString(Silent) + '"';

  // Encapsulate
  if Result <> '' then
    Result := EncapsulateXML('audio', '', Result);
end;

{ TNotification }

function TNotification.BuildXMLDoc: TXMLInterface;
begin
  Result := StringToXMLDocument( ToXML );
end;

constructor TNotification.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FTitle := 'Hello world!';
  FText := 'This is a notification';

  FXML := CreateNewXMLInterface;
end;

destructor TNotification.Destroy;
begin
  FXML := nil;

  inherited;
end;

function TNotification.ToXML: string;
function TextToXML(Value: string): string;
begin
  if Value <> '' then
    Result := EncapsulateXML('text', Value)
  else
    Result := '';
end;
begin
  Result := '';

  Result := Result + '<toast activationType="protocol">';
    // Visual
    Result := Result + '<visual>';
      Result := Result + '<binding template="ToastGeneric">';
        // Text
        Result := Result + TextToXML(Title);
        Result := Result + TextToXML(Text);
        Result := Result + TextToXML(TextExtra);

        // Extra
        Result := Result + Image.ToXML;
        Result := Result + Progress.ToXML;
      Result := Result + '</binding>';
    Result := Result + '</visual>';

    // Input
    const Input = Input.ToXML;
    if Input <> '' then
    Result := Result + EncapsulateXML('actions', Input);

    // Audio
    Result := Result + Audio.ToXML;

    // Header
    Result := Result + Header.ToXML;
  Result := Result + '</toast>';
end;

procedure TNotification.UpdateToastInterface;
begin
  FToast := nil;

  FToast := TToastNotification.CreateToastNotification(BuildXMLDoc);
end;

{ TNotificationProgress }

function TNotificationProgress.ToXML: string;
begin
  Result := '';

  // Check disabled/invalid
  if Status = '' then
    Exit;

  if Title <> '' then
    Result := Result + 'title="' + Title + '" ';

  Result := Result + 'status="' + Status + '" ';
  Result := Result + 'value="' + Value.ToString + '" ';

  if ValueOverride <> '' then
    Result := Result + 'valueStringOverride="' + ValueOverride + '"';

  // Encapsulate
  if Result <> '' then
    Result := EncapsulateXML('progress', '', Result);
end;

{ TNotificationImage }

function TNotificationImage.ToXML: string;
begin
  Result := '';

  // Check disabled/invalid
  if Source = '' then
    Exit;

  if ImageQuery <> '' then
    Result := Result + 'addImageQuery="' + ImageQuery + '" ';

  if Alt <> '' then
    Result := Result + 'alt="' + Alt + '" ';

  Result := Result + 'src="' + Source + '" ';

  case Placement of
    TImagePlacement.Hero: Result := Result + 'placement="hero" ';
    TImagePlacement.LogoOverride: Result := Result + 'placement="appLogoOverride" ';
  end;

  case HintCrop of
    TImageCrop.Circle: Result := Result + 'hint-crop="circle" ';
  end;

  // Encapsulate
  if Result <> '' then
    Result := EncapsulateXML('image', '', Result);
end;

{ TInputItem }

function TInputItem.ToXML: string;
begin
  Result := '';

  // Check disabled/invalid
  if ID = '' then
    Exit;

  Result := Result + 'id="' + ID + '" ';
  Result := Result + 'content="' + Content + '" ';

  // Encapsulate
  if Result <> '' then
    Result := EncapsulateXML('selection', '', Result);
end;

{ TNotificationInput }

function TNotificationInput.ToXML: string;
var
  Inputs: string;
  I: integer;
begin
  Result := '';

  // Check disabled/invalid
  if ID = '' then
    Exit;

  Result := Result + 'id="' + ID + '" ';

  case InputType of
    TInputType.Text: Result := Result + 'type="text" ';
    TInputType.Selection: Result := Result + 'type="selection" ';
  end;

  if PlaceHolder <> '' then
    Result := Result + 'placeHolderContent="' + PlaceHolder + '" ';

  if Title <> '' then
    Result := Result + 'title="' + Title + '" ';

  // Inputs
  Inputs := '';
  if Length(Selections) > 0 then
    for I := 0 to High(Inputs) do
      Inputs := Inputs + Selections[I].ToXML;

  // Encapsulate
  if Result <> '' then
    Result := EncapsulateXML('input', Inputs, Result);
end;

{ TNotificationManager }

constructor TNotificationManager.Create;
begin
  FApplicationName := ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName);

  RebuildNotifier;
end;

function TNotificationManager.CreateNewNotification: TNotification;
begin
  Result := TNotification.Create;
end;

destructor TNotificationManager.Destroy;
begin
  FNotifier := nil;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TNotificationManager.HideNotification(Notification: TNotification);
begin
  if Notification.Toast = nil then
    raise Exception.Create(NOTIF_BUILD_ERR);

  FNotifier.Hide(Notification.Toast);
end;

procedure TNotificationManager.RebuildNotifier;
var
  AName: HSTRING;
begin
  FNotifier := nil;

  AName := StringToRTString(FApplicationName);
  FNotifier := TToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(AName);
  WindowsDeleteString(AName);
end;

procedure TNotificationManager.SetAppName(const Value: string);
begin
  if FApplicationName = Value then
    Exit;

  FApplicationName := Value;
  RebuildNotifier;
end;

procedure TNotificationManager.ShowNotification(Notification: TNotification);
begin
  if Notification.Toast = nil then
    raise Exception.Create(NOTIF_BUILD_ERR);

  FNotifier.Show(Notification.Toast);
end;

{ TNotificationHeader }

function TNotificationHeader.ToXML: string;
begin
  Result := '';

  // Check disabled/invalid
  if (ID = '') or (Title = '') or (Arguments = '') then
    Exit;

  Result := Result + 'id="' + ID + '" ';
  Result := Result + 'title="' + Title + '" ';
  Result := Result + 'arguments="' + Arguments + '" ';

  if ActivationType <> '' then
    Result := Result + 'activationType="' + ActivationType + '" ';

  // Encapsulate
  if Result <> '' then
    Result := EncapsulateXML('header', '', Result);
end;

end.
```

To open a notification, do as follows:

```
var
  Manager: TNotificationManager;
  Notif: TNotification;
begin
  Manager := TNotificationManager.Create;
  try
    Manager.ApplicationName := 'Awesome Application';

    Notif := Manager.CreateNewNotification;

    Notif.Title := 'This is the title';
    Notif.Text := 'This is the text';

    Notif.Image.Source := 'C:\Windows\System32\@facial-recognition-windows-hello.gif';
    Notif.Image.Placement := TImagePlacement.Hero;

    Notif.Audio.Sound := TSoundEventValue.NotificationIM;
    Notif.Progress.Value := 0.5;
    Notif.Progress.Status := 'Downloading data';

    Notif.UpdateToastInterface;

    Manager.ShowNotification(Notif);
  finally
    Manager.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you !

Comment: @delphirules Also, this way of changing the app name is not the most ideal method. As this sets the app `Identifier` to the string you enter. With this code, you lose the ability to have a notification icon, or customize the notification in the Settings app. The proper way to do this is by adding a record for your app in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\AppUserModelId\. The name of the key is the `Identifier` provided in `TToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier`. If you would like, I can provide a updated version of the code.

Comment: please, if you could do it, i'd appreciate

Comment: @delphirules I have added the source code to GitHub, It may receive updates in the future to be able to receive notification close status, buttons and such. https://github.com/Codrax/Cod-Notification-Manager